# Finding length of an edge with a few variables known

Tags: geometry, kinematics, robotics

I need to solve an inverse kinematics problem with geometric approach for a robotic arm and I've constructed a geometric system for my system, I've uploaded the picture System geometry. 
[image]
I need to calculate the z length, but only the x value is known, is there a way I can manage to solve this system? I've tried triangle similarity, etc... but could not solve it yet.

Edit: I think the picture is unclear, so you gave a minus for the question. Here 135 and 170(the upper red line) are the length of the robot arm, z is the lower red line and x is the value that user gives as an input(say it is 10 for example), so h can be computer with ptyhagoras from(135^2=h^2 + x^2) and Q can be calculated from Q=atan2(x,h). However, the a angle (between 135 and 170) is unknown.

Comment: Is $h$ known? What about $Q$?

Comment: @5xum since x is known and the 135 value is given h can be calculated from pythagoras and Q can be calculated from atan2(x,h). I need to calculate z for corresponding x.

Comment: Oh, so that's what the 135 means. It's all quite confusing.

Comment: @5xum sorry I've tried to draw with paint and I am not very good at it, here 135 and 170 are the arm lengths of the robot arm and x is a value that user gives as an input.

Comment: If angle $a$ is unknown it should be clear that there are many possible values for $z$.

Comment: @Aretino yes unfortunately, if I can at least find a few equations that leads to z value it will help solving the problem

Comment: Maybe you have a range of accettable values for $z$?

Comment: @N74 it can be said $z$ is between 0 and 105

Comment: As much ad I understand your ribot arm, I think you should fix $z$ and vary $a$.

Comment: @N74 the problem here is I need to find the z variable.

Comment: I was trying to make you rethink your problem: you have both the angles of the robot arms easily programmable, I don't know what is in the "z" arm, but you canput a fixed length tool there to make your system easier. Anyway, $z=0$ covers al the possibile range for $x$ (0 to 135).

Comment: To have $z=0$ you have to program $a=Q+\cos^{-1}h/170$.

Comment: @N74 I've tried to represent the height with $z$, this 170 arm goes to forward and when it goes further the length represended with $z$ gets lower in real life, that's why I try to relate these edges.I think I could not simplfy my 3-,D problem to a 2-D one truly. That's why it seems unsolvable or not understood. Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Your problem is 2D, I don't see any problem in solving it. We are trying to understand what are your real needs. From your last comment it seems you are moving only $Q$ leaving $a$ fixed. If this is the case you need to know what is the $a$ value or, at least, a couple of corresponding values $x_0, z_0$.

Comment: actually $a$ changes too with $z$, but $Q$ is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A formula for $z$ can be readily found:
$$
z=h-170\cos(a-Q),
$$
but that depends on the value of angle $a$, which is arbitrary.

Comment: so I need to have at least a range for $a$ thank you for your answer I try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the design of your robot arm, basically you have one segment, the 135 one, that can rotate around the lower left point, and you have another segment, the 170 segment, attached to the first segment by a joint, which is the point where 170 meets 135. The 170 segment is also allowed to freely rotate around the joint. If this is your system, then you do not have enough input parameters. This system has two degrees of freedom (the configuration space is the two dimensional torus = a circle times a circle, or some subsurface of that, like a cylinder or a quadrilateral) and requires two input parameters to fully determine its configuration. You either have to allow the user to determine two parameters or you need to put another restriction to your robot arm so that its configuration space becomes one-dimensional.

For instance, input parameters could be $x$ and $z$ chosen in some appropriate intervals. Or $x$ and $y$, where $x+y$ is the length of the horizontal segment of the rectangle around your arm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you are partly rigth. In order to clarify the robot mechanism [here](http://dobot.cc/dobot-armv1/product-overview.html)  is my robotic arm. The problem is the z parameter is affected by x, so the user can't assign the parameter, I've tried to measure the other unknowns with ruler on robot, but always got inaccurate results.

Comment: The parameter $z$ is not determined by $x$. And technically this robot arm has one extra degree of freedom. Its configuration space is the three dimensional torus (or subspace of it). And I do not think that $z$ is affected by $x$. You can fix $x$ and still change $z$ within some interval. Do you have the distance from the lower left corner of the rectangle to the point where $z$ intersects the horizontal edge of the rectangle? I think that's the most important parameter, it tells you where the end of the robot arm is. Only parameter $x$ is not enough. Ever.

Comment: I think my problem is thinking in 3-D but constructing the equations in 2-D, by the way the length seems to be (170+x).